# Cuando quiero eliminar de un formulario en php en un mvc el php del controlador se ejecuta pero ni hace cambios en la base de datos ni devuelve nada

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mvc

Este es el controlador:

```php
<?php

$ide_cli= empty($_GET['ide_cli']) ? 0 : $_GET['ide_cli'];

require_once "../Db/Con1Db.php";

require_once "../Models/EliminarClientes1Model.php";



$oData = new Datos;


$sql = "DELETE FROM Cliente WHERE ide_cli = ?";

$data = $oData->setDataPreparedStatements1($sql, $ide_cli);



?>
```

Este es el modelo:

```
<?php

class Datos{

    private $mysqli;
    private $data;
    

    public function __construct()
        {
            $this->mysqli=Connection::conn1();
            $this->data=array();
        }

    // Asegúrate de que estás pasando el número correcto de parámetros a bind_param
    public function setDataPreparedStatements1($sql, $par1)
    {
        $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);

        // Aquí, 'i' indica que estás pasando un parámetro de tipo integer
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $par1);

        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            $result = "La operación no se ha podido realizar.";
        } else {
            $result = "Operación realizada con éxito.";
            
        }

// Cerrar la sentencia preparada
        $this->mysqli->close();
        return $result;
    }

}

?>
```

Este es el js:

```js
function deshabilitarControl1(control1)
{
    control1.classList.remove("boton1");
    control1.classList.add("boton1Inhabilitado");
    control1.disabled = true;
}

function habilitarControl1(control1)
{
    control1.classList.remove("boton1Inhabilitado");
    control1.classList.add("boton1");
    control1.disabled = false;
}

/* INICIO - ajaxPost1 - Devuelve el resultado a un DIV (POST) */
function ajaxPost1(form1, controlador1, div1)
{

  // 1.- Creación del objeto XMLHttpRequest (Ajax1)
  const Ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // 2.- Enlace del formulario a un objeto FormData (FormData1)
  const FormData1 = new FormData( form1 );
  
  // 5.-Éxito en el envío
  Ajax1.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    document.getElementById(div1.id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
  });
  
  // 5.-Error en el envío
  Ajax1.addEventListener("error", function( event ) {
    alert( 'Error: no se ha enviado la informacion' );
  } );
  
  // 3.-Configuración del envío del formulario a través del FormData
  Ajax1.open("POST", controlador1);
  
  // 4.-Envío del formulario a través del FormData
  Ajax1.send( FormData1 );
  
}
/* FIN - ajaxPost1 - Devuelve el resultado a un DIV (POST) */

/* INICIO - ajaxPost2 - Devuelve el resultado a una Alert (POST) */
function ajaxPost2(form1, controlador1, div1)
{

  // 1.- Creación del objeto XMLHttpRequest (Ajax1)
  const Ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // 2.- Enlace del formulario a un objeto FormData (FormData1)
  const FormData1 = new FormData( form1 );
  
  // 5.-Éxito en el envío
  Ajax1.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    alert(this.responseText);
  });
  
  // 5.-Error en el envío
  Ajax1.addEventListener("error", function( event ) {
    alert( 'Error: no se ha enviado la informacion' );
  } );
  
  // 3.-Configuración del envío del formulario a través del FormData
  Ajax1.open("POST", controlador1);
  
  // 4.-Envío del formulario a través del FormData
  Ajax1.send( FormData1 );
  
}
/* FIN - ajaxPost2 - Devuelve el resultado a una Alert (POST) */

/* INICIO - ajaxGet1 - Devuelve el resultado a un DIV (GET) */
function ajaxGet1(controlador1, div1) {
 
  let ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById(div1.id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  ajax1.open("GET", controlador1, true);
  ajax1.send();

}

function ajaxGet2(controlador2, div1) {
 
  let ajax1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax1.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById(div1.id).innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  ajax1.open("GET", controlador2, true);
  ajax1.send();

}
/* FIN - ajaxGet1 - Devuelve el resultado a un DIV (GET) */

function seleccionarDatos1(form1, boton1, controlador1, div1)
{    
    deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
    ajaxPost1(form1,controlador1,div1);
    habilitarControl1(boton1);
    form1.reset();
}

function seleccionarDatos2(form1, boton1, controlador1, div1)
{
  deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
  ajaxGet1(controlador1, div1);
  habilitarControl1(boton1);
  form1.reset();
}

function seleccionarDatos4(form1, boton1, controlador2, div1)
{
  deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
  ajaxGet2(controlador2, div1);
  habilitarControl1(boton1);
  form1.reset();
}

function seleccionarDatos3(form1, boton1, controlador1, div1)
{
  deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
  ajaxGet1(controlador1+'?valor=' + campo1.value, div1);
  //ajaxGet1('Controllers/Buscador1Controller.php?valor=' + campo1.value, divResultado1.id);
  habilitarControl1(boton1);
  form1.reset();
}

function insertarDatos1(form1, boton1, controlador1, div1)
{      
  deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
  // Opcion 1: El mensaje se muestra en un div (ajaxPost1)
  ajaxPost1(form1,controlador1,div1);
  // Opcion 2: El mensaje se muestra en una alert (ajaxPost2)
  // ajaxPost2(form1,controlador1,div1);
  habilitarControl1(boton1);
  form1.reset();
}

function modificarDatos1(form1, boton1, controlador1, div1)
{      
  deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
  // Opcion 1: El mensaje se muestra en un div (ajaxPost1)
  ajaxPost1(form1,controlador1,div1);
  // Opcion 2: El mensaje se muestra en una alert (ajaxPost2)
  // ajaxPost2(form1,controlador1,div1);
  habilitarControl1(boton1);
}

function modificarDatos2(boton1, controlador1, div1) {      
  deshabilitarControl1(boton1);
  // Opción 1: El mensaje se muestra en un div (ajaxGet1)
  ajaxGet1(controlador1, div1);
  // Opción 2: El mensaje se muestra en una alerta (ajaxPost2)
  // ajaxPost2(form1, controlador1, div1);
  habilitarControl1(boton1);
}



window.addEventListener('load', function(){

  let boton1;
  let boton2;
  let controlador1;
  let controlador2;
  let div1;
  let div2;
  
    /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (submit) LogIn */
    // Paso 1: Obtener referencias:
    const formLogIn1 = document.getElementById("formLogIn1");
    // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
    if(formLogIn1)
    {
      // Referencia de los elementos
      boton1 = document.getElementById("botonLogIn1");
      controlador1 = "Controllers/Index1Controller.php";
      div1 = document.getElementById("container");
      // Evento y llamada a la función
      formLogIn1.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        insertarDatos1(formLogIn1,boton1,controlador1,div1);
      });
    }
    /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (submit) LogIn */

  /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (submit) Insertar 1 */
  // Paso 1: Obtener referencias:
  const formInsercion1 = document.getElementById("formInsercion1");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(formInsercion1)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    boton1 = document.getElementById("botonInsercion1");
    controlador1 = "Controllers/InsercionClientes1Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor1");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    formInsercion1.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      insertarDatos1(formInsercion1,boton1,controlador1,div1);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (submit) Insertar 1 */

  /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (submit) Insertar 2 */
  // Paso 1: Obtener referencias:
  const formInsercion2 = document.getElementById("formInsercion2");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(formInsercion2)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    boton1 = document.getElementById("botonInsercion2");
    controlador1 = "Controllers/InsercionProveedores1Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor1");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    formInsercion2.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      insertarDatos1(formInsercion2,boton1,controlador1,div1);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (submit) Insertar 2 */

  /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (submit) Insertar 2 */
  // Paso 1: Obtener referencias:
  const formInsercion3 = document.getElementById("formInsercion3");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(formInsercion3)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    boton1 = document.getElementById("botonInsercion3");
    controlador1 = "Controllers/InsercionProductos1Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor1");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    formInsercion3.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      insertarDatos1(formInsercion3,boton1,controlador1,div1);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (submit) Insertar 2 */

  /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (submit) Insertar 2 */
  // Paso 1: Obtener referencias:
  const formInsercion4 = document.getElementById("formInsercion4");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(formInsercion4)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    boton1 = document.getElementById("botonInsercion4");
    controlador1 = "Controllers/InsercionEmpleados1Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor1");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    formInsercion4.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      insertarDatos1(formInsercion4,boton1,controlador1,div1);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (submit) Insertar 2 */

  /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (click) Seleccionar 2 */
  // Paso 1 - Referencia del elemento que tiene asociado el evento
  const botonConsulta2 = document.getElementById("botonConsulta2");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento y llamada a la función
  if(botonConsulta2)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    controlador2 = "Controllers/ConsultaClientes2Controller.php";
    div2 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    botonConsulta2.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      seleccionarDatos2(formConsulta1,botonConsulta2,controlador2,div2);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (click) Seleccionar 2 */

    /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (click) Seleccionar 2 */
  // Paso 1 - Referencia del elemento que tiene asociado el evento
  const botonConsulta4 = document.getElementById("botonConsulta4");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento y llamada a la función
  if(botonConsulta4)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    controlador2 = "Controllers/ConsultaProveedores2Controller.php";
    div2 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    botonConsulta4.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      seleccionarDatos2(formConsulta2,botonConsulta4,controlador2,div2);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (click) Seleccionar 2 */

  /* ---------------------------------- INICIO - (submit) Insertar 3 */
  // Paso 1: Obtener referencias:
  const formEdicion1 = document.getElementById("formEdicion1");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(formEdicion1)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    boton1 = document.getElementById("botonEdicion1");
    controlador1 = "Controllers/EdicionClientes2Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    formEdicion1.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      modificarDatos1(formEdicion1,boton1,controlador1,div1);
    });
  }
  /* ---------------------------------- FIN - (submit) Insertar 3 */
  
  const formEdicion2 = document.getElementById("formEdicion2");
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(formEdicion2)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    boton1 = document.getElementById("botonEdicion2");
    controlador1 = "Controllers/EdicionProveedor2Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    formEdicion2.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      modificarDatos1(formEdicion2,boton1,controlador1,div1);
    });
  }

  const botoneliminar1 = document.getElementById("botonEliminacion1")
  // Paso 2 - Asociación del elemento al evento (submit) y llamada a la función
  if(botoneliminar1)
  {
    // Referencia de los elementos
    
    controlador2 = "Controllers/EliminarClientes1Controller.php";
    div1 = document.getElementById("contenedor2");
    // Evento y llamada a la función
    botoneliminar1.addEventListener("click", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      modificarDatos2(botoneliminar1,controlador2,div1);
    });
  }
});
```

Y esta la vista:

```html
<?php require_once "Controllers/EdicionClientes1Controller.php"; ?>
<div id="contenedor0" class="contenedor0">
    <div id="contenedor1" class="contenedor1">
        <h1>Modificar</h1>
        <form id="formEdicion1" class="bloque1 row">
            <input type="hidden" id="textoEdicion0" name="textoEdicion0" required class="campo1" placeholder="Identificador" value="<?php echo $_GET['ide_cli']; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion1" name="textoEdicion1" required class="campo1" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $nom_cli; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion2" name="textoEdicion2" required class="campo1" placeholder="Apellidos" value="<?php echo $ape_cli; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion3" name="textoEdicion3" required class="campo1" placeholder="Nombre Empresa" value="<?php echo $emp_nom_cli; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion4" name="textoEdicion4" required class="campo1" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo $ema_cli; ?>">
            <input type="number" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion5" name="textoEdicion5" required class="campo1" placeholder="Teléfono" value="<?php echo $tel_cli; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion6" name="textoEdicion6" required class="campo1" placeholder="Dirección" value="<?php echo $dir_cli; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion7" name="textoEdicion7" required class="campo1" placeholder="Ciudad" value="<?php echo $ciu_cli; ?>">
            <input type="text" class="col-4 form-control" id="textoEdicion8" name="textoEdicion8" required class="campo1" placeholder="Código Postal" value="<?php echo $cpo_cli; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class="col-4 form-control" id="botonEdicion1" name="botonEdicion1" value="Actualizar" class="boton1">
            <input type="button" class="col-4 form-control" id="botonEliminacion1" name="botonEliminacion1" value="Eliminar" class="boton1">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor2" class="color-blanco contenedor2"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Que errores te da? Lee el [tour] para saber como funciona SOes. Y lee también [ask].